# Create a column in a table that matches a specific pattern

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

Hi I am quite a beginner in pl/sql and I try to create a table with a column that should match a pattern consisting of five character string with the two first characters are letter and the other three are numbers with no `NULL` and don't start with zero.
I have tried the alter table modify option but I get an error that what I am trying to do is not an `ALTER TABLE` option

```
CREATE TABLE my_course
(my_course_firstyear VARCHAR2(2),
my_course_secondyear NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
my_course_final VARCHAR2(10)); 

ALTER TABLE my_course
modify
my_course_final VARCHAR2(20),
my_course_secondyear || mycoursefinal);
```

Of course this is not working but I just can't work out how to set constraints when a column is a combination of letters and numbers.

I'd appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your description in the first paragraph, the constraint that you want is a check constraint.  You can set it using a regular expression:

```
alter table my_course add constraint chk_column
    check (regexp_like(column, '^[a-zA-Z]{2}[1-9][0-9][0-9]$'));
```

Constraints can also be included in the `create table` statement.

Note that if the column is going to be five characters, you should declare it as `CHAR(5)`.

I am not sure what the code has to do with the description of the problem.